# How to change which device my AppleID's 2FA "Pin Code" is sent to

Tags: apple-id, two-factor-authentication

I have an single AppleId for multiple devices - about 20 devices (and rising).

Every time I get a new device, I need to sign into App Store using my AppleId. In doing so, I get asked for a 2FA pin code. This pin code is sent to the same Macbook Air. If that device is not handy, I need to the say 'did not receive code' and then select my phone *number* (txt/sms message) as the next way to receive the code, which works fine.

Is there any way I can define which device will receive the initial Pin Code popup box with the verification pin code?